# iOS 7 generating crash on stringByAppendingString which is working fine in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ios7

I am developing simple application of keypad. In this I am using `stringByAppendingString`. this api works fine in iOS 6 but crashes in iOS7. below is my code,

```
-(void)updateEditTextWithPressedDigit:(NSInteger)buttonTag :(UIButton *)button
{
    switch (button.tag) 
    {
        case 10:
            dialedNumber = [dialedNumber stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
            break;
        case 11:
            dialedNumber = [dialedNumber stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
            break;
        case 12:
            dialedNumber = [dialedNumber stringByAppendingString:@"#"];
            break;
        default:
            dialedNumber = [dialedNumber stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",buttonTag]];
            break;
    }

    dialedDigitField.text = dialedNumber;
}
```

here, `dialedNumber` is `NSString` variable.

Why does it crashes on `stringByAppendingString`?

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Please add crash log.

Comment: Most likely because dialedNumber has gone bye-bye.  It was dumb luck that it didn't happen with 6.

Comment: this code is working fine in ios7. what is your error?

Comment: Please show us where you create (and destroy) `dialedNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use property instead of instance variable if You not very familiar with memory management.

Answer (score 0):

You must only have dialedNumber created once, and it's being cleaned up after updateEditTextWithPressedDigit goes out of scope.  Consider making dialedNumber a property of the object implementing the method shown and access it with self.dialedNumber or _dialedNumber.